# Comparing Auto-regressive Encoder-Decoders and Topological Neural Networks

Tags: machine-learning, linear-algebra, topology

I am interested in what insights can be gained about the mathematical class of auto-regressive encoder-decoders (LLMs), by comparing them to topological neural networks.

Specifically, I am looking for similarities and differences in their structures, behaviors, and mathematical properties.

In the context of this question, an LLM is a type of neural network that is designed to generate sequences of data, such as sentences in a language. It does this by learning to predict the next item in a sequence based on the previous items.

Any insights, references, or resources that could help clarify this would be greatly appreciated.

References:

1. [Building an Autoencoder for Generative Models](https://dev.to/kayis/building-an-autoencoder-for-generative-models-3e1i)